# Cypher to show relationships of hidden nodes

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I’m a total beginner in Cypher and I’m struggling to obtain the result I want.

So I have nodes that all have a property called « level ». I want to keep only a certain level, but I want to recreate the missing links.

Here is my dataset:

[image]

in CSV:

```
n
"{owner:Team A,name:MySubscription,level:1}"
"{name:Database,level:2}"
"{owner:Team A,name:Service A,level:3}"
"{owner:Team A,name:MyTopic,level:2}"
"{name:Service B,level:3}"
"{name:Service C,level:3}"
"{name:MySecret,level:1}"
```

I want to keep only the nodes that are `level >= 2` but I want to recreate the links like so:

[image]

Could you help me create the query that does just this?

Comment: Is it really useful to use CSV when every row is made of a single JSON column?

Comment: I agree, but Neo4J Browser exports data like this. Do you want me to export it using another way?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's the better way to do it. But I did found the answer:

```
MATCH (a:Asset)-[rel]-(b:Asset) WHERE a.level >= 2 AND b.level >= 2 
RETURN a, rel, b

UNION

MATCH (a:Asset) -[:USING]-(:Asset)-[:ATTACHED]-(b:Asset) WHERE a.level >= 2 
AND b.level >= 2
CALL apoc.create.vRelationship(a,'USING',{}, b) YIELD rel
RETURN a, rel, b

UNION

MATCH (a) WHERE NOT (a)--() 
RETURN a, null as rel, null as b;
```